# Retrieve json from a website after login on webview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am working on an app which involves pulling course information from student's portal. On the user's side:

1. Student is brought to a webview showing the login page from university's website. (https://acorn.utoronto.ca/)
2. Student puts in the credentials (Utorid and password), clicks login, webview is closed, and student is brought back to the app and will see his/her courses nicely imported and arranged.

Meanwhile, the app should:

1. Go into user's personal portal page upon successful login and take the user back to app while process the following in background
2. *Click* on "Enrol & Manage" in the left sidebar (not sure if it is necessary, but when I view the source on my browser upon login, sometimes XHRs folder doesn't show unless click on that link)
3. Go to XHRs folder and find the json "enrolledCourses" (https://acorn.utoronto.ca/sws/rest/dashboard/courseRegistration/enrolledCourses)
4. Retrieve and parse the user's course info and make them available for the app

[Source view when student just logged in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYXqD.png)

[Source view when student click on "Enrol & Manage" in the left sidebar, as you can see now "XHRs" is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCL8F.png)

[The file "enrolledCourses" in "XHRs" which contains the course information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McjPv.png)

Here's my code for the ViewController so far:

```
import UIKit
import HTMLKit
import WebKit

class UtoridViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    
    private let webView: WKWebView = {
        let webView_result = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
        return webView_result
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        print("Acorn loading")
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(webView)
        
        webView.frame = view.bounds
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        
        // Covert URL_string into URL
        guard let url = URL(string: Constants.ACORN_URL) else {
            return
        }
        
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
}

extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!){
        
        
    }
}
```

**So far, I can get the user to the website, but I have no idea how to proceed...**

**Any help or guidance will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!!!**

Answer (score 0):

its impossible, data on another process...

why don't you want to send an http request to the server and get the required data? if I'm not mistaken, you can take cookies from the webView and use them already for the request

there is of course an option through getting html code or executing arbitrary JS code, but this is a very unstable solution